# Android video stream

Tags: android, stream, rtmp

I want to play video stream on my android app.
I found code from a website `<div>
    <a id="rtmp_player" style="display: block; height: 560px; width: 720px; background-color: #ffffff; border: solid 1px #ccc; alighn: center;"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        $f("rtmp_player", "/onvideo/flowplayer-3.2.10.swf", {
            clip: {
                url: 'stream1',
                live: true,
                provider: 'rtmp'
            },
            plugins: {
                rtmp: {
                    url: '/onvideo/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10.swf',
                    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://195.210.47.196/live'
                }
            }
        });
         // ]]>
    </script>
</div>`
So How can I play this stream in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Use VideoView for this. Try below code :

```
     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://YOURCOMPUTER_SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/");
     mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just USE VITAMIO SDK. and url will be rtmp://195.210.47.196/live/stream1